# Can I Write Two Partial Models In Single View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I Want To Add Two Partial Models in One View

Because I want to add some fields of MSTDepartmentmaster On The View Of MSTCityMaster

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<auto_increment.Models.MSTCityMaster>" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<auto_increment.Models.MSTDepartmentMaster>" %>
```

[image]

Comment: You can use the idea of partial views

Comment: There is nothing about models in that code, and you appear to want modules in the title: try rewriting to be very specific about what you are trying to do *and* why (in the question).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the help files, in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not possible to inherit the single view by multiple different classes.

If you use two partial in a view then you can use both different class in different partials and use them in your view.

Comment: Thank You Sir... How It be possible can u give one example